# Issues with checkboxes adjacent to Dojo tab titles

Tags: checkbox, tabs, dojo

I have a Dojo tab container with six tabs and each tab has an iframe.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; " >
  <div   data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"  id="tabContainer" >
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Action Items" data-dojo-props="selected:true" id="pane1">
        <iframe  id="frame1" src="source1.html"></iframe>
    </div>  
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Action Items" data-dojo-props="selected:true" id="pane2">
        <iframe  id="frame2" src="source2.html"></iframe>
    </div>  
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Action Items" data-dojo-props="selected:true" id="pane3">
        <iframe  id="frame3" src="source3.html"></iframe>
    </div>  
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Action Items" data-dojo-props="selected:true" id="pane4">
        <iframe  id="frame4" src="source4.html"></iframe>
    </div>  
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Action Items" data-dojo-props="selected:true" id="pane5">
        <iframe  id="frame5" src="source5.html"></iframe>
    </div>  
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Action Items" data-dojo-props="selected:true" id="pane6">
        <iframe  id="frame6" src="source6.html"></iframe>
    </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

The title of each pane has a checkbox adjacent to the title, place there with the following code:

```
 dojo.query("#tabContainer .dijitTabPane").forEach(function(n){
      new dijit.form.CheckBox({ 
          checked: true,
          id: "check"+n.id,
          //This event added as a result of issue 1
          onChange: function(b) {  
              var container = dijit.byId("tabContainer");
              var tab = dijit.byId("check"+n.id);
              container.selectChild(tab);
          }
      }).placeAt("tabContainer_tablist_"+n.id, "first");
 });
```

Issue #1: When I click a checkbox associated with a tab, the tab does not change.

Issue #2: When I click the checkbox associated with a tab, the onChange event clears the entire pane.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle to replicate the issue? I tried using the code you provided, but I don't think it looks the way you see it. http://jsfiddle.net/D5JpT/

Comment: I did not post the dojo code that actually creates the tabs.  I will edit the jsfiddle shortly.

Comment: jsfiddle is not working.  I copied and pasted an existing jsfiddle with dojo tabs (http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/aGCFs) and am not getting the same result when I post it over the one you created.  I tried changing dojo versions.  I added the dojo.requires to the top of the javascript section, and when I look at the firefox web console, it is showing "TypeError: dojo.require is not a function"

Comment: That's because the code you put in the fiddle is entirely different from the code you posted here.

Comment: I am just trying to get SOMETHING to work in the fiddle before worrying about my code.

Comment: Again, I tried posting http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/N2hsG/ to your existing fiddle, as well as to a brand new fiddle, and it isn't showing the tabs.

Comment: When I copy my code over the existing fiddles that work, mine also works (after replacing the '/' with '.')

Comment: Although I cannot get the checkboxes to display next to the tab titles now. *sigh*